# regex to replace first or second gradient color

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

need to replace first or second gradient color, like this:

```js
var x = 1;
var new_color = 'rgb(140,220,0)';
var sty = $('#targ').attr('style');
if(x == 1){
  var first_rgb = '???'; // regex here to get `rgb(255,102,255)`
  var new_sty = sty.replace(first_rgb, new_color);
}
else{
  var second_rgb = '???'; // regex here to get `rgb(255,0,0)`
  var new_sty = sty.replace(second_rgb, new_color);
}
$('#targ').attr('style', new_sty)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="targ" style="background:linear-gradient(to right, rgb(255,102,255), rgb(255,0,0)); color:black; padding:25px 9px 14px 9px;">LOREM</div>
```

Any help?

Comment: Why not just use `sty.replace('rgb(255,102,255)', new_color);`

Comment: @Nick - rgb... is a variable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use these two regex to find the different `rgb`s to be replaced:

```
rgb\([^)]*?\)(?=[^)]*rgb)
```

looks for `rgb(` followed by some number of non-`)` characters and a `)`, with a lookahead assertion that the match is followed by `rgb` again after some number of non-`)` characters.

```
rgb\([^)]*?\)(?=\s*\))
```

looks for `rgb(` followed by some number of non-`)` characters and a `)`, with a lookahead assertion that the match is followed by some number of spaces and a `)`.

```js
var new_color = 'rgb(140,220,0)';
var sty = $('#targ').attr('style');
var re = [
  /rgb\([^)]*?\)(?=[^)]*rgb)/,
  /rgb\([^)]*?\)(?=\s*\))/
];
for (let x = 0; x < 2; x++) {
  var new_sty = sty.replace(re[x], new_color);
  $('#targ' + x).attr('style', new_sty)
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="targ" style="background:linear-gradient(to right, rgb(255,102,255), rgb(255,0,0)); color:black; padding:25px 9px 14px 9px;">LOREM</div>
<div id="targ0" style="background:linear-gradient(to right, rgb(255,102,255), rgb(255,0,0)); color:black; padding:25px 9px 14px 9px;">LOREM</div>
<div id="targ1" style="background:linear-gradient(to right, rgb(255,102,255), rgb(255,0,0)); color:black; padding:25px 9px 14px 9px;">LOREM</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here we go, Only works for browser supports ECMAScript 2018.

```js
var first_rgb = /rgb\(.*?\)/;

var second_rgb = /(?<=rgb.*?)rgb\(.*?\)/;

var sty = "background:linear-gradient(to right, rgb(255,102,255), rgb(255,0,0)); color:black; padding:25px 9px 14px 9px;";

var new_color = 'rgb(140,220,0)';

console.log('[sty]: ' + sty);

console.log("[first rgb replaced]: " + sty.replace(first_rgb, new_color));

console.log("[second rgb replaced]: " + sty.replace(second_rgb, new_color));
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd try to make the regex specific to matching gradients to prevent replacing any other rgb values and use a function to replace in the right one:

```js
let x = 1;
let new_color = 'rgb(140,220,0)';
let sty = $('#targ').attr('style');
let new_sty = sty.replace(
  /-gradient\(.+(rgb\(\d{1,3},\d{1,3},\d{1,3}\))\s*,\s*(rgb\(\d{1,3},\d{1,3},\d{1,3}\))/,
  (match, first, second) => match.replace(
    first, x==1?new_color:first).replace(second, x==1?second:new_color));
$('#targ').attr('style', new_sty);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="targ" style="background:linear-gradient(to right, rgb(255,102,255), rgb(255,0,0)); color:black; padding:25px 9px 14px 9px;">LOREM</div>
```